# Can I run a second wordpress site as a subdomain without using multisite?

Tags: multisite

I have an two wordpress sites that I would like to host on the same domain. One is already up and running, the other is sitting in waiting.

Can I get the second as a subdomain, or simple within a folder, to run on the same domain (different DB) without converting to multisite?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Point the subdomain to the same directory as the main site, and define different settings in your **wp-config.php** per `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`:

Example from my local setup:

```
switch ( $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] )
{
    case 'zzl.dev':
        $table_prefix = 'zzl_';
        $table_name   = 'zzl';
        break;

    case 'wpbuch.dev':
        $table_prefix = 'wpbuch_';
        $table_name   = 'wpbuch';
        break;

    default:
        $table_prefix  = 'wp_';
        $table_name   = 'wpdev';
        break;
}

$sub                 = '/wp-content/' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
const WP_CONTENT_DIR = __DIR__ . $sub;
const WP_CONTENT_URL = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $sub;
const DB_NAME        = $table_name;
```

You can change much more variables in the switch: all `DB_*` definitions, `WP_PLUGIN_DIR` and `WP_PLUGIN_URL` (to share the plugin list between different sites), `WPLANG` and so on.

Comment: Is this all I have to do to add a subdomain?

Comment: @Mild Fuzz: Yes, I’m running several live sites with this setting, even some multisites.

Comment: so this is just a case of having all themes and plugins in the same install, and just calling the different databases? Ultimately it is one install?

Comment: @Mild Fuzz Yes, it is. If you update one site, the other sites are up to date too. Try it in your local setup, it’s a matter of minutes.

Comment: @toscho How does this work out when you come to upgrade plugins and wordpress? Does it play nice?

Comment: @Brady Yes, it works like in a usual installation. You get the update nags in every site’s backend if you haven’t suppressed it per plugin.

Comment: The **risk** with this set up is all the static upload files are inter mingled into single wp-upload directory (unless you have a way to separate them?). Not a recommended way to run multiple sites. Professionally I would never recommend this, WordPress multi site was created for a purpose.

Comment: @Azizur: Usually, I set the options `'upload_path'` and `'upload_url_path'` per [installation plugin](https://github.com/toscho/WordPress-Basic-Settings). And `wp_unique_filename()` prevents collisions. But you are right, one should take care to separate the directories.

Comment: @toscho there remains lat problems: what about the `SALTs` and etc constants?  How can i generate them manually to put there individually?

Comment: @T.Todua Just add them in the `switch` statement. Albeit separate salts aren't needed locally.

Comment: @toscho maybe you are right, but i prefer high security, even on  localhost, because 1 suspicious , 1 minute-tried plugin might infect whole my localhost, and all sites, so I'd like more safety..... 
so, what I mean, when I create a new site, then how would I know salts for it, while it is not still generated (as it's new site being to be installed, just defining database-name in advance) ?  Or can i simply use other site's salt lines, just by changing even 1 letter in those salts?

Comment: @T.Todua Local salts are *only* needed if your computer is open to the world. And in that case, they won't protect you anyway. You try to fix the wrong thing.

Answer (score 0):

As addition to @toscho's excellent answer, I will add several things...

## ======== Safety ========

Always be careful with safety. If you try to use any test site in this manner (with many sites paralelly) and on that test site you'll install any crappy/suspicious plugin, which might infect whole WP-Core, then all your other sites will be under risk (although,that risk similarly exists even while you use completely separated installations). This is just a small thing, however, dont worry much about it (because worrying wont help at all).

## ======== Needed steps to setup on Localhost =======

To point subdomain to main WP-INSTALLATION (while just using special `wp-config.php`), you need to set-up `Alias` commands in webserver.

1) Go to `..wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\conf\httpd.conf` and  uncomment this line: `Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`

2) in `extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` add (just modify to your specifics. In the below example, I use already setup domain name `localhost`... however, you can add anything)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
                    #UNCOMMENT_THIS_LINE_ONLY_WHEN_YOU_NEED_SUBFOLDER_TOO#  Alias /subdirectory_name    C:\wamp\www\wp_installation_folder
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias subdomain.localhost
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    DocumentRoot "C:\wamp\www\wp_installation_folder"
    ErrorLog "logs/4-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/4-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

3) *[You dont need to do this step if you use `localhost` name]* In case you with to use you anything other than `localhost`, then you should point that name in `C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts, like:`127.0.0.1  myexample.org`

**Restart WampServer and that's all**